# Both create and list in the same view MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4. I know basic CRUD functionality in MVC, but how can I achieve both create and list in the same view? Like after a user creates data the user will automatically be redirected to the same view and view the list of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use partial views to accomplish this. Create the create / edit pages the same way as you do and below the form you may render a partial view that would render the list with even edit / delete buttons.

Alternatively, you may pass both the form data (in case of edit) and the list data to a view to render there.

I would suggest you to use the partial views approach as it would simplify the view and the partial view can be reused on some other page also.

> Please take this as a starting point and not as a follow-it-blindly solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.without partial view can i achieve this ?

Comment: Yes this can be very well achieved without using partial views. It's just that you'll have to pass the data you want to show to the view. You may create a `ViewModel` for this, if needed.